# ERROR: No matching distribution found for qvd

Tags: python, windows, pip

I'm trying to pip install [qvd](https://pypi.org/project/qvd/) on my windows machine.
I'm running on Windows 10 64bit and python 3.10.2

```
> C:\users\[...]> pip install qvd
> 
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement qvd
> (from versions: none)
> 
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for qvd '''
```

Installing other packages is not a problem and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this answer [qvd only supports Python 3.6 - 3.9](https://pypi.org/project/qvd/#files).

Downgrade to an appropriate version of Python or wait for `qvd` to update.